# Gold linker problems

Tags: c, linker, gold-linker

I am checking out gold linker to see if it speeds up the linking process.
I changed the soft link of `ld` in `/etc/alternative/ld` to point to `/usr/bin/gold.ld`, which I see it does.

The result is that linking time only got much slower and the worst thing is that the linking fails from a reason I don't understand.

Does anyone have experience with transitioning to gold linker?
How do I use the parallel linking in it? (by using top commands I only saw 1 `ld` process).

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

> Does anyone have experience with transitioning to gold linker?

Yes.

(I realize this is a mostly useless answer, but that's because you've asked a useless question.)

> How do I use the parallel linking in it?

Gold linker needs to be configured with `--enable-threads`, which is not the default.

If the linker is configured with thread support, then `--thread` and `--thread-count COUNT` are the flags you are looking for ([man page](http://manpages.sgvulcan.com/ld.gold.1.php)).

Note however, that in my experience `ld.gold` is 4-6 times faster than `ld.bfd` *without* using threads, and threads are certainly not going to cure your link failure.

Your best bet is to try to understand that link failure, and fix whatever the problem is. Once you've done that, there is a high chance that `ld.gold` will be faster as well.

Comment: here is the failure: " /usr/bin/ld: fatal error: cannot mix -r with dynamic object ../libm.so". any idea what it means?
i was able to do --enable-threads in the EXTRA_LDFLAGS but the other two flags failed linkage even though the flag appear in the man page in linux (the link you gave did not work).
any ideas?
thanks

Comment: @itayb "here is the failure" -- your link command line is incorrect. Remove `-r` from it.